# What does “avoid the teeth” mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

What does the phrase “avoid the teeth” mean? It makes no sense to me.
Here is the context:

> High School is just one big buzz saw that grinds people up into little byte-sized pieces. Some people just do a better job **at avoiding the teeth**.

I tried to find out what it means, using Google, reverso context and urban dictionary, but have found nothing.

Source: https://youtu.be/h8ZA40pwpMA?t=26s (0:26)

Comment: Is there a clue in the caption to the video?

Comment: @WillCrawford what do you mean?

Comment: Before you edited the rest of the quote into your question, I followed the link, and the first thing I saw was the description of the video, which *is* the first part of your quote, and I thought the "saw" part might be a hint about what the "teeth". Sorry :)

Comment: It's a bit of a mixed metaphor - the teeth of a buzz-saw might feasibly ***chew** you up*, but they can't ***grind** you up*. That would be a ***millstone***. Given how big a millstone is though, I can't see how the figurative usage [***a millstone around his neck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22millstone+around+his+neck%22) (a great encumbrance) ever caught on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your clip starts at 0.26 seconds into the episode.  A few seconds earlier the voice-over says"

> High School is one big buzz-saw that grinds people up into little pieces.

Obviously this should not be taken literally. It means that some people have a really hard time in High School.

Immediately after that the voice-over says the line that you are querying. So, "the teeth" she is referring to are the teeth of the buzz-saw. In other words, she is expecting to coast through High School without any of the major problems that other students will have.

Comment: To be clear, we call the sharp ridged edge of a saw the "teeth".  http://www.blackburntools.com/articles/saw-tooth-geometry/images/rake.gif

Comment: Technically it's the little ridges / peaks that we call the teeth ;o) Never heard anyone call the edge a "jaw" though.